# Stripe Payment CURL issue

Tags: curl, stripe-payments

I have following code that allows me to make a Stripe Payment from CLI.

```
curl -u stripe-secret-key-here: -d amount=100 -d currency=gbp -d 
'card[number]=4242424242424242' -d 'card[exp_month]=5' -d 'card[exp_year]=2015' 
https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges
```

However if I try to use the following from the URL/Asterisk Dial Plan then I receive below given error.

```
https://stripe-secret-key-here:@api.stripe.com/v1/charges?amount=100&
currency=gbp&card[number]=4242424242424242&card[exp_month]=5&card[exp_year]=2015
```

Error:

```
{
"error": {
"type": "invalid_request_error",
"message": "Received unknown parameter: card",
"param": "card"
}
}
```

Would appreciate a little help...
Thanks.

Comment: Try "" around your url.

Comment: hi, it gives same error....https://stripe-secret-key-here:@api.stripe.com/v1/charges?amount=100&currency=gbp&"card[number]=4242424242424242"&"card[exp_month]=5"&"card[exp_year]=2015"

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is an old question, it still shows up as one of the most relevant when searching for `stripe-payments`, so I thought I'd offer an answer.

The reason the request fails when using the URL form is because this would be a GET request.

The [Stripe API documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api) notes clearly that [charge creation requests](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#create_charge) are POST requests.

When using `curl` with the `-d` option, the request is sent as POST. From the [cURL manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html):

> POST (HTTP)
>
> It's easy to post data using curl. This is done using the `-d <data>`
>   option.  The post data must be urlencoded.

So the reason you get the "unknown parameter: card" error is because the `https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges` endpoint expects only two different types of GET requests: [charge retrieval](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#retrieve_charge) and [list charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#list_charges), neither of which expect a `card` parameter.

More information on GET vs. POST :

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to generate a stripe card token using the `card` params you trying to pass instead of passing the card params.

Example:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges \
   -u YOUR_SECRET_KEY: \
   -d amount=2000 \
   -d currency=usd \
   -d source=tok_visa \
   -d description="Charge for james.martin@example.com"
```